# how to add new menu item to an existing odoo module?

Tags: module, menuitem, odoo-8

I want to add new menu item in human resources module.

I create new module depends of "hr" module.

and I create an xml file to add new menu and field.

this my code:

```
<menuitem id="menu_new" parent="menu_hr_root" name="new" sequence="30"/>
```

I update module list and I reload the page but I didn't find the new menu.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Just we must need to add the parent id based on your dependent module name then after your depended menu id in your **parent Attribute**

some think like this

```xml
<menuitem name="Performance Appraisal" parent="your_module_name.menu_eval_hr" id="menu_open_per_appri_req"
        action="action_menu_perf_app_rel"/>
```

**Menu Attribute**

1. **name**=name of your menu
2. **id**=unique id for each menu item
3. **string** = Name of your string which you want display in your view form
   not string attribute is not define then the menu string
   automatically set as your menu action name
4. **action**=name of your action which you want to call
5. **parent**=**your_dependent_module_name.parent menu id** in your child menu
   if your parent menu is in your same module then the dependent module name is not needed to add in your  parent attribute
6. **sequence** =Define the sequence for the menu displaying in your view

I hope this should helpful for you ..:)

Comment: I must put the action tag ?, and there is an analogy to put the sequence number?

Comment: sequence is not needed but  when you have many child then it compulsory to make and add the sequence of your each child menu for your view.

Comment: action attribute can be as the call  view action like tree view ,search view,form view or any other view as well as your wizard action call

Comment: But what should the action refer to? All tags i see with id that are in the action of some <menuitem/> are <record>.... But i don't quite get it... Can my action point to some other tag other than <record>? And what's the difference

Comment: <record> contain arch which containts (views) <form>,<search>,<tree> and when we make separate action for separate view or make it as single action for diff views and we will make the menu for call that action using action attribute of that menu so It may calling base on menu click . In your explanation action menu and <record> tag which is totally different.

Comment: What if the thing I want to open is not in a <record> tag. I am using the <report> tag to define a report. The report of course has an ID, but defining a menu item so that the action is the ID of the report does not open the report.